# How do I setup Ubuntu in VMware with a different network physically?

Tags: vmware

I have Ubuntu server on VMWare, I'm trying to setup a html page with ubuntu. I was given the IP 172.16.110.223 to use on my ubuntu VM. However, I am now on my home network, which is 192.168.1.71. When I try to ping the 172.16.110.1 default gateway on ubuntu, it says destination unreachable, and the html page is not accessible. How can I configure this correctly? I have VMware settings on NAT. Heres my `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 172.16.110.223
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 172.16.110.1
domain-name t933.lab
dns-search t933.lab
dns-nameservers 172.16.110.2
```

Answer (score 0):

172.16.*.* and 192.168.*.* are both private address ranges and the machines in question are located in different (private) networks. It's possible to interconnect multiple private networks and translate network addresses between them if both of them allow it. This procedure is called a Virtual Private Network. You should ask the system administration department of your school or university about available VPN options to connect to its network.